# Change css class of button clicked in angular with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, class, angularjs-ng-repeat, this

This is what I want to do:

- I get json from an api: ✓
- I use ng-repeat to display all the data as a button: ✓
- The user can click a button: ✓
- if the data attribute for that particular button was "premier", log "premier", if it was "random", then log random: ✓
- if the data attribute of this button was "premier", the class should be "btn-danger disabled" : ✗

I'm working in a laravel blade document, so I have to skip angular's double curly brackets by placing an @ in front, like this: @{{ xxx }}.

The code at the moment correctly logs the data-correct attribute. But it changes the class of **all** the buttons, not only the one clicked.

My code:

html:

```
<a href ng-click="validateClick(premier.correct, $index)"
           ng-class="{premier: isPremier, random: isRandom}"
           ng-repeat="premier in premiers"
           class="btn btn-default btn-game"
           data-correct="@{{premier.correct}}"
           href="#"
           role="button">
                @{{premier.name}}
</a>
```

app.js:

```
$scope.validateClick = function(row, index) {
    if (row == "premier") {
        $scope.isPremier = true;
        console.log($scope.isPremier + index)
    }
    else {
        $scope.isRandom = true;
        console.log($scope.isRandom + index)
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason that the class is being changed for all the rows of the ng-repeat is due to the fact they are all pointing to the same scope boolean value ($scope.isPremier). One solution to this problem it to give each object in the repeat it own isPremier property and use that value to set the class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jared. Do you mind to explain with code? I'm not that familiar with angular actually.

Comment: @Karthik Easwaran's answer below is what I was describing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of assigning to the common scope variable assign it to the premier object and use it in the class

HTML

```
<div ng-click="validateClick(premier, $index)" ng-class="{premier: premier.isPremier, random: premier.isRandom}" ng-repeat="premier in premiers" class="btn btn-default btn-game" data-correct="{{premier.correct}}" href="#" role="button">
                {{premier.name}}
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.validateClick = function (premier, index) {
        if (premier.correct == "premier") {
            premier.isPremier = true;
            console.log(premier.isPremier + index)
        } else {
            premier.isRandom = true;
            console.log(premier.isRandom + index)
        }
    }
```

Working sample is available in the jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/cce2g6y2/1/